# Good Form for Random Number Generator?

Tags: javascript, random

I wanted to get a few opinions on doing a random number generator. I read through a couple different ways to do it and this is the way that I created after doing a little reading. Is it acceptable form? Any foreseeable issues?

```
function master() {
   function generate() { 
      var pickFrom = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
      var j = pickFrom.length;
      // Generates a random number
      var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * j + 1); 
      // Picks a number based on what number was picked.
      var code = pickFrom.charAt(i); 
      document.write(code);
   }

   x = 1;
   while(x) {
      generate();
      x--;
   }
}

master();
```

Comment: I don't think you need to add one to `Math.random()*j`. `string.charAt` is zero-based. Also you can use `pickFrom[i]` directly instead of calling `charAt`.

Comment: Minus the little details already mentioned, that is "sufficient" (e.g. for general non-crypto use) - so, "not a real question" as it is. (Also, `charAt(i)` will convert the number to an appropriate [[Int32]], via a truncate, so ..)

Comment: If you are going to have x > 1, then there seems to be no reason for having `pickFrom` and `j` declarations inside `generate()` function.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the application and what your going for, performance, efficiency or what.

I actually used this reference a while back when needing a very solid and performance driven random generator. This should help :)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharpgeneral/thread/fd8664ac-aa75-47df-94b8-b64580dab93c